# C++ using command line args

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I intend to enter a number into the command line such as saying "./a.out 3" where 3 would be the number I'm trying to retrieve.  I'm wondering why in my example, the two numbers I'm trying to output aren't the same, and what is the most practical way of extracting info from the command line args?  Thanks

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


    char* openSpace = argv[1];
    int temp = *openSpace;

    cout<<*openSpace<<" is the open spot!"<<endl;
    cout<<temp<<" is the open spot!"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`argv[1]` is a `char*` and you want an `int`.  Unfortunately, you cannot just change the type of the variable.  Instead, you must convert the `char*` to an `int`.  Use the `atoi()` function for this.

```
int temp = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Comment: Take a look at boost's lexical_cast also.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean, they are not the same? Surely they are! The first print the character '3' as character and the second prints it as an integer. That is you get ASCII value of the character '3'.

If you want to get it an integer value you can use something like `atoi()`, `strtol()`, `boost::lexical_cast<int>()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can not convert string to integer using an assignment like `int temp = *openSpace;`. You need to call a function for that, like `atoi()` from standard C library.